# redirect to view from another view NoReverseMatch error django

Tags: python, django

Helo everyone, I have two views but I can't redirect to view from another view.
Before asking this question I tried some solutions from stackoverflow, but they they didn't bring any result. Please help.

VIEWS.py

```
def new_room(request):
    new_room = None
    while not new_room:
        with transaction.atomic():
            label = haikunator.haikunate()
            if Room.objects.filter(label=label).exists():
                continue
            new_room = Room.objects.create(label=label)
    return redirect('chat', label=label)

def chat(request, label):
   room, created = Room.objects.get_or_create(label=label)
   messages = reversed(room.messages.order_by('-timestamp')[:50])

   return render(request, "chat/room.html", {
       'room': room,
       'messages': messages,
   })
```

URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^new/$', views.new_room, name='new_room'),
    url(r'^(?P<label>[\w-]{,50})/$', views.chat, name='room'),
]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `redirect` looks like it's using the name of a function rather than the name of a named view. We would need to see your urls.py to be sure.

Remember, `redirect` uses `reverse` under the hood - you'll need to supply the same name you use in your URL patterns, as well as any necessary namespace. If you can post your existing urls.py files I can try to provide more concrete information on how to fix your problem. In the meantime review the examples of how to use `redirect` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples

Comment: so I have posted urls.py. please tell me what do I need to do)

Comment: You're trying to redirect to a view named `chat`, but in your `urls.py` you named the view `room`. Redirecting to `room` should work just fine. Remember to include the namespace if necessary (for instance, if this is all in an app called `chatapp` then you might need to redirect to `chatapp:room`).

Comment: as my app's name is chat I tried Chat:room and now it works)))) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should show your url conf in the question, the redirection is by named urls, not function names.

Your url conf should have:

```
from .views import chat

url(r'^chat/$', chat, name='chat')
```